# Cross Product Without Numpy

Tags: python, cross-product

When I am trying to take the cross product of vectors A and B it is returning an error: 'int' object is not subscriptable.

If someone could help me understand this that would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I am trying to do the cross product without using numpy.

```
A = [3, 4, 8]
B = [6, 2, 1]


def cross(A, B):
    c = [A[1] * B[2] - A[2] * B[1],
         A[2] * B[0] - A[0] * B[2],
         A[0] * B[1] - A[1] * B[0]]

    return c
print("The cross product of A cross B is: \n", cross(A, B))
```

Comment: This code works fine, I suspect you have a typo somewhere in you original code.

Comment: Yes, I got it to work. How would I get it to print without the commas separating the numbers?

Comment: `res = cross(A, B)` then `print(f'The cross product of A cross B is: [ {res[0]} {res[1]} {res[2]}')` and you don't need the `\n` it is added automatically.